# Como acceder al valor de un boton en JS. No formulario

Tags: javascript, html, botón, contentvalues

que tal? Quisiera acceder al valor de estos botones, pero de la forma que lo hice no me funciona. No tengo que usar .input.value, por que no es un input. Pero no estoy logrando acceder. Saludos!

```js
let opcionesUCM = document.querySelectorAll(".ucm > .pregunta__opcion")
let opcionesUCMValue = opcionesUCM.value
```

```html
                    <div class="div__pregunta ucm">
 <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">¿Por quien consigue Clint la gema del Alma?</h2>
  <img src="">
  <button class="pregunta__opcion opcion__correcta">Viuda Negra </button>
  <button class="pregunta__opcion">Bruja Escarlata</button>
  <button class="pregunta__opcion">Gamora</button>
  <button class="pregunta__opcion">Carol Danvers</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Primero que nada, creo que estás planteando mal el funcionamiento de tu pregunta. Obviamente no tienes un `value` porque es un botón... pero ya que estás usando botones... por qué no les enlazas una acción en el click en vez de intentar coger su valor desde otra parte?? No tiene mucho sentido usar botones e intentar adivinar cual se ha pulsado mirando el valor que tienen... son botones, enlázales una función y listo! Por ejemplo `onclick="checkAnswer('ucm', 1)"`, así en el método checkAnswer puedes mirar qué pregunta es y qué opción se eligió...

Comment: Y para concretar un poco más sobre tu error... además de no tener un `value`, `querySelectorAll()` devuelve un ARRAY, no un único elemento... tendrías que iterar sobre él o hacer algo como `let opcionesUCMValue = opcionesUCM[0].value`.

Comment: Okey, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Tambien puedes asignar el click al document (delegar eventos) y con el event target obtienes todo lo referente al elemento clickeado

Answer (score 1):

Vale, creo comprender lo que quieres hacer, así que te comparto el código y me dices si es correcto.

Javascript y HTML:

```js
  var a = document.querySelectorAll(".ucm > .pregunta__opcion")
  a.forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener('click', function(){
      checkAnswer(e.id)
    })
  })
function checkAnswer(id){
  idB= id;
  alert(document.getElementById(idB).value)
}
```

```html
<div class="div__pregunta ucm">
 <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">¿Por quien consigue Clint la gema del Alma?</h2>
  <img src="">
  <button value="Viuda Negra" class="pregunta__opcion opcion__correcta" id="1">Viuda Negra </button>
  <button value="Bruja Escarlata" class="pregunta__opcion" id="2">Bruja Escarlata</button>
  <button value="Gamora" class="pregunta__opcion" id="3">Gamora</button>
  <button value="Carol Danvers" class="pregunta__opcion" id="4">Carol Danvers</button>

</div>
```

Lo que hace esto, es devolverte el valor que tiene el botón en un alert cada vez que lo presionas. Espero te sirva